# Jquery Accordion within an accordion

Tags: jquery

I want to create a sortable list within another sortable list. For this I am using accordion within an accordion.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
$( function() {
$( "#accordion" )
  .accordion({
    header: "> div > h3"
  })
  .sortable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: "h3",
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
      // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
      // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
      ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );

      // Refresh accordion to handle new order
      $( this ).accordion( "refresh" );
    }
  });
  });

  $(function () {
      $("#accordion1")
          .accordion({
              header: "> div > h3"
          })
          .sortable({
              axis: "y",
              handle: "h3",
              stop: function (event, ui) {
                  // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                  // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                  ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");

                  // Refresh accordion to handle new order
                  $(this).accordion("refresh");
              }
          });
  });
```

```
<div style="padding:5px">
        <div id="accordion1">
        <asp:ListView ID="lstSList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lstSList_ItemDataBound">
        <LayoutTemplate> 
            <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
                <tr class="TableHeader">     
                    <td> Section Description</td>              
                </tr>

                <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>No Sections found</EmptyDataTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>           
                <div class="group">
                        <h3><%#Eval("Description")%></h3>
                  <div>    
                    <div style="padding:5px;display:none" id="pnlSectionQuestions">
                        <asp:ListView ID="lstQuestionList" runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>                    
                                <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>                   
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>No questions added for this section</EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="group">
                            <tr class="TableData">
                                <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QuestionDesc")%>' /></td>                       
                                <td><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Tag")%>' /></td>
                                <td runat="server"> <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btnEdit" style="margin-top:5px" onclick='<%#Eval("QuestionId","editClicked({0})") %>'>Edit</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>        
        </ItemTemplate>         
        </asp:ListView>
       </div>
    </div>
```

c# code:

```
 protected void lstSList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListView lstSectionQuestionList = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lstSectionQuestionList");

        SQLHelper sq = new SQLHelper();
        lstSectionQuestionList.DataSource = sq.GetQuestionBySectionId(25);
        lstSectionQuestionList.DataBind();

    }
}
```

The first accordion renders properly and is sortable but it does not show the second listview within the first accordion (It shows all the rows at the end of the first listview.).
Please advise how can I resolve this.

Comment: Think you forgot to add something here. There is only ONE accordion (<div id="accordion1">) in your HTML.

Comment: Yes I am not sure how to add it as I am using a listview it will create a div with same id every time and that will not work.

Comment: You just need to add a HeaderTemplate and a FooterTemplate and put the beginning of the accordion in the header and the end div in the FooterTemplate, it looks a bit weird in that sense, but that's how it works.

Comment: Oh, damn.. you are using a ListView.. Well, if you switch to an asp:repeater all roads lead to Rome.. ;) Well, except it doesn't support LayoutTemplate and EmptyTemplate..